# Get a unique device ID (same when connected to other systems) for headphones connected to system

Tags: c#

I want to fetch a unique ID specific to my headphones connected as a PnP to my system.
This ID should be same when I connect headphones to some other system.

I have tried using DeviceId and PNPDeviceId, but I am getting different values when connected to other systems.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity");

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            if (queryObj["Description"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("audio"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DeviceID: {0}", queryObj["DeviceID"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);
                Console.WriteLine("PNPDeviceID: {0}", queryObj["PNPDeviceID"]);
            }
        }
```

Below are the values I got for the same headphones:

```
DeviceID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0662&SUBSYS_17AA3070&REV_1001\4&A87FB78&0&0001
Description: High Definition Audio Device
PNPDeviceID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0662&SUBSYS_17AA3070&REV_1001\4&A87FB78&0&0001
```

and

```
DeviceID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_11D4&DEV_1984&SUBSYS_10280211&REV_1004\4&851744B&0&0001
Description: High Definition Audio Device
PNPDeviceID: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_11D4&DEV_1984&SUBSYS_10280211&REV_1004\4&851744B&0&0001
```

Is there any way to get a unique ID for the device?

Comment: Are those usb headphones or audio-jack headphones? If it's the latter case there may be no chip to actually store any UUID.

Comment: Those values aren't for the headphones at all, but for the sound circuit which sends a signal to the headphone port.

Comment: Those are audio-jack hps.

Comment: Is there any way to get some unique identifier for my device